# Finding minimum value of $\sqrt{x^2-2x+1} + \sqrt{x^2-6x+13}$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, quadratics, radicals, maxima-minima

How can I minimize $f$, where
$$f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-2x+1} + \sqrt{x^2-6x+13}$$

I know how to minimize a quadratic equation. But I don't know how to minimize a case like this where two quadratics are involved and that too inside a square root function.

Comment: Hint $x^2-2x+1=(x-1)^2$.

Comment: OP: Please do not modify your question after some answer is posted. Here, you changing $\sqrt{x^2-2x+1}$ into $\sqrt{x^2-2x+2}$ unduly makes @kimchi's answer irrelevant. (I reverted your edit.)

Comment: My original question had been edited by someone making that 2 a 1 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Minkowski (triangle inequality) we obtain:
$$\sqrt{x^2-2x+1}+\sqrt{x^2-6x+13}=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+0^2}+\sqrt{(3-x)^2+2^2}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{(x-1+3-x)^2+(0+2)^2}=2\sqrt2.$$
The equality occurs for $x=1$, which says that $2\sqrt2$ is a minimal value.

Similarly we obtain:
$$\sqrt{x^2-2x+2}+\sqrt{x^2-6x+13}=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+1^2}+\sqrt{(3-x)^2+2^2}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{(x-1+3-x)^2+(1+2)^2}=\sqrt{13}.$$
The equality occurs for $(x-1,1)||(3-x,2)$, id est, for $x=\frac{5}{3}$.

Comment: How did you bring the two quadratics under the same square root sign ?

Comment: @Anmol Agarwal It's a triangle inequality: Let $A(a_1,a_2)$, $B(b_1,b_2)$, $C(c_1,c_2)$, Hence, $\vec{AB}(b_1-a_1,b_2-a_2)$, $\vec{AC}(c_1-a_1,c_2-a_2)$ and $\vec{CB}(b_1-c_1,b_2-c_2)$ and since $AC+CB\geq AB$, we obtain: $\sqrt{(c_1-a_1)^2+(c_2-a_2)^2}+\sqrt{(b_1-c_1)^2+(b_2-c_2)^2}\geq\sqrt{(b_1-a_1)^2+(b_2-a_2)^2}$. You can see that $c_1-a_1+b_1-c_1=b_1-a_1$ and $c_2-a_2+b_2-c_2=b_2-a_2$

Answer (score 1):

To minimize $f(x)=\sqrt{(x^2-2x+2)} + \sqrt{(x^2-6x+13)}$, you can do this directly by taking the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$:
$$
\color{green}{f'(x)=\frac{2 x-2}{2 \sqrt{x^2-2 x+2}} + \frac{2 x-6}{2 \sqrt{x^2-6 x+13}}}
$$
and set it equal to zero: $\color{blue}{f'(x)=0}$. Now, solve for $x$: 
$$ 
\frac{2 x-2}{2 \sqrt{x^2-2 x+2}} =- \frac{2 x-6}{2 \sqrt{x^2-6 x+13}} 
$$ 
implies 
$$ 
(x-1)\sqrt{x^2-6 x+13} =- (x-3)\sqrt{x^2-2 x+2} \hspace{8mm} (\spadesuit)
$$ 
by clearing the denominators. 
Square both sides to get: 
$$
(x-1)^2 (x^2-6 x+13) =(x-3)^2 (x^2-2 x+2)  \hspace{8mm} (\diamondsuit)
$$
or 
$$
3 x^2-2 x-5=(x+1)(3x-5)=0. 
$$
So $x=-1$ or $x=5/3$. 
Since 
$$
f(-1) = 1 + 2 \sqrt{2}  \cong 3.82843 \hspace{4mm}\mbox{ and }\hspace{4mm} f(5/3) = \sqrt{13}\cong  3.60555, 
$$
we conclude that $f$ attains its minimum when $\color{magenta}{\boxed{x=5/3}}$.

$\textbf{Remark}.$ Note that $x=-1$ is $\textit{not}$ a significant point of $f$. It appeared as it if were a critical point when we went from $(\spadesuit)$ to $(\diamondsuit)$ by squaring both sides. As a further analysis, here is a plot of
$g(x)=(x-1)\sqrt{x^2-6 x+13} + (x-3)\sqrt{x^2-2 x+2}$: 
[image: plot-of-g]
and here is a plot of 
$h(x) = (x-1)^2 (x^2-6 x+13) -(x-3)^2 (x^2-2 x+2)$: 
[image: plot-of-h].

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to complete the square, to find where the quadratics are minimized. Each of the two summands in your $f$ is piecewise concave. (Graph them to see what I mean.)  The first term, $|x-1|$, is concave on $(-\infty,1]$ and concave on $[1,+\infty)$. The second is concave on $(-\infty,3]$ and concave on $[3,+\infty)$.  So your $f$ is concave on each of the intervals $(\infty,1]$, $[1,3]$, and $[3,+\infty).$  Now use the fact that a concave function can attain its minimum on an interval only at an endpoint.  That gives you 4 endpoints to check ($\pm\infty$, $1$, and $3$); the one that gives the smallest $f$ is what you are looking for.